# How to remove space followed by line break in python?

Tags: python, line-breaks

I have this string: `'time. \nAlthough'`

What I wanna do is remove all spaces followed by a line break. I tried the following but my it doesn't remove anything:

```
phrase = """
time. ​

Although 
"""

phrase = phrase.replace(' \n','')
print(phrase)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you want to remove space or line break?

Comment: Ok try this phrase = phrase.replace('\n','') There is a space before \n

Comment: On WIndows it might be `\r\n`, so looking for ` \n` would not find anything

Comment: Are you sure that there really is a `" \n"` in your string? Some systems/programs use a `carriage-return` so what you're trying to replace might be `" \r\n"` instead.

Comment: @MericOzcan when I do that then I get "time. ​Although" whereas I want the output to be "time.Although"

Comment: Check my answer I changed it, it does what you need

Comment: The string in the posted code has a 200b (zero-width space) character between the regular space and the newline.  That's why your replace fails.  The single-line string at the top of your posting does not have that character, and the `replace` works fine on that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the string you pasted contains an "invisible character". To see this, you can call `repr` on your string:

```py
phrase = """
time. ​

Although 
"""
repr(phrase)
## >>> "'\\ntime. \\u200b\\n\\nAlthough'"
```

A quick look online shows that `\\u200b` is a "[zero-width-space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)".

You'll have to change your replace to factor this in, or figure out how that zero-width-space got into your string in the first place.

```py
phrase = phrase.replace(" \u200b\n", "")
print(phrase)
## 
## time.
## Although
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
import re
phrase = """
time. 

Although 
"""
phrase = re.sub(r"\s+$", "", phrase, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

---

Explanation:
[image]

---

- [Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/5d7aa54fa6)
- [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/huGd31/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are expecting is to just remove the space leaving `\n` (newline) there. If it is so, you can try this code:

```
phrase = """
time. ​

Although 
"""

phrase = phrase.replace(' \n','\n')    # Leaving newline and removes the white space
print(phrase)
```

Or if you want to remove the following newline alone, you can try this:

```
phrase = """
time. ​

Although 
"""

phrase = phrase.replace('\n','')    # Leaving newline and removes the white space

print(phrase)
```

Comment: The first example would not explain why it removes nothing for OP

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you, I made that because it would remove an extra space before the newline character